# Using OS data, some sea tiles are the wrong colour

Tags: qgis

Using OS data and CRS ESPG:27700, Some blocks of sea tiles are showing the wrong blue colour, how do I change these tiles to the correct colour please?

[image]

Comment: please add a screen shot to help people see what the issue is

Comment: How do I add the screenshot please?

Comment: post it on a server and paste the link into the question - you don't have enough reputation to add it directly yet.

Comment: Hopefully this is a link to the image in onedrive, wrong colour seatiles on both sides of the bottom of The Isle of Wight. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8694227D0595230!4182&authkey=!AHcoixAlMlWQ62k&v=3&ithint=photo%2cJPG

Comment: which product are you using?

Comment: QGIS 2.14.0 - Essen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37451/discussion-between-derek-and-iant).

Answer (score 1):

You can double-click the tile raster (or right-click the layer and go to *Layer Properties)* and go to the **Style** tab. From here, you can change the colour of tiles.

Example: to change the colour of tiles with this light blue (which has the value `1`) to a darker blue, double-click the colour:

[image: Example]

Choose the new colour and click **OK**:

[image: Set colour]

Finally, click **Apply** to see the new colour:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi Joseph For some reason when I pick on a tile in QGIS, it won't stay still and also on the Layers button the properties is not available but is there in a light colour?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using raster tiles? You won't be able to select individual tiles (unless you want to convert your raster tile to a polygons) as each cell in the image contains a specific value which are represented by a chosen colour. You should have access to the whole colour spectrum, perhaps you could [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/186471/edit) your question to include screenshots?

Comment: How do I add the screenshot please? And yes I have used Raster data but as I have built a virtual raster and used that.

Comment: When you edit your question, you can see a list of icons for **bolding** or _italicising_ text etc. The 6th icon from the left allows you to upload image files. For your virtual raster, the same method applies. You just need to becareful that changing the colour for a value will affect all cells with that value.

Comment: Hopefully this is a link to the image in onedrive, wrong colour seatiles on both sides of the bottom of The Isle of Wight. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8694227D0595230!4182&authkey=!AHcoixAlMlWQ62k&v=3&ithint=photo%2cJPG

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? Could you upload your virtual raster to onedrive?

Comment: The version is QGIS 2.14.0- Essen, the Raster is the whole of the South West of England including South Wales, so would be a bit big

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37450/discussion-between-derek-and-joseph).